# Laravel 4 Input::old() not working

Tags: laravel-4

```
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Undefined offset: 0"
```

**MyController.php**

Input::old() is empty. How to store some data in the input old? sorry for my english =D

```
return View::make('ajax.view')
                    ->withInput()
                    ->withErrors($validation)
                    ->render();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass over the data into the View:

```
return View::make('ajax.view')
    ->withInput(Input::all())
    ->withErrors($validation)
    ->render();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's works! =D

```
Input::flash();
return View::make('ajax.view')
                    ->withInput(Input::all())
                    ->withErrors($validation)
                    ->render();
```

Comment: Youre a life saver!